# Syslog server redundancy

Tags: linux, rsyslog

Gentlemen ,

There’s a requirement for syslog server redundancy.
Most of the syslog clients are network devices and appliances on which you can configure only one syslog server as destination.
I been thinking about keepalived and  virtual up shared between two syslog servers, so if one will be down, logs will be send to secondary server.
All looks good on the paper.
Anyone tried this? Will this work? There won’t be any data inconsistency?
Or maybe we can achieve this differently? Ideas are welcome.

To be done on RedHat8 with rsyslog.

Thanks!

Comment: Having a virtual ip that moves between multiple servers is a very common way to provide redundant syslog service.